# How to find a specific class in python using beautifuldsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

From `<section id="ref78299" data-level="1" data-has-spy="true"><h2 class="h1"><span id="ref613779"></span>Land</h2>` I am just extracting `class="h1"` because I need string between this `<span id="ref613779"></span>Land</h2>` and its working but the problem is that its not giving me results for all  occurrence `class="h1"` its just gave me a result for a first occurrence of  `class="h1"`
Hower occurrence of `class='h1` in `<section id="ref273744" data-level="1" data-has-spy="true"><h2 class="h1"><span id="ref613784"></span>People</h2>`
Here website link `https://www.britannica.com/place/Alabama-state` from which I am trying to extract that string at that website(htmlcontent) more than two occurrence of `class='h1` but I am just giving you a example of two from that website.
My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
htmlrequests=requests.get('https://www.britannica.com/place/Alabama-state')
htmlcontent=htmlrequests.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlcontent,'html.parser')
for section in soup.find_all(class_='h1'):
    print(section.text)
```

and output is:`Land` and expected `Land` `People`
is it enough to explain my problem ,waiting for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
# Python program to print all heading tags
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
# scraping a wikipedia article
url_link = 'https://www.britannica.com/place/Alabama-state'
request = requests.get(url_link)
 
Soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')
 
# creating a list of all common heading tags
heading_tags = ["h1", "h2", "h3"]
for tags in Soup.find_all(heading_tags):
    print(tags.name + ' -> ' + tags.text.strip())
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @ ASH No its not a result I  want If You visit that website you saw  at the left that there are categories like Land, Poeple, Economy and more  I want to just extract names of that Titles  but my cods gives me first title not all.How did I do that?any Idea

Comment: thats  a  problem that you also find all `h1,h2,h3`  in  soup but it didin't shows all` h1,h2,h3` tags ,However when you inspect manually that website you will saw that there are more `h1,h2,h3` tags ,, Inshort I want to find all of  thses tags from a soup or a website.waiting for your help.